# iOS 4.x/5.0 - push notifications for background/multitasking apps?

Tags: ios4, background, push-notification, multitasking

Is there  a way to get an app to receive the remote push notification while it is in the background?

I don't want to see the regular (close,view ) notification on my device. i want to go silently into the app - and the app will do it's magic from their...showing it's own AlertView (with custom buttons, and playing the alert sound (even when the device is on mute)

Is that possible?? How can i convince apple to support such scenario?

Update: What about in iOS 5.0? is there going to be a change regarding the push notification mechanism now that it uses the notification center?

Comment: you might need a lot of money

Comment: Shouldn't be a wide request for it from other application developers as well? everyone that uses push notification and now got in the background ...if he wants the push - why not get it (in-app ) and not the regular iphone push (close/view annoying popup)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you probably out of luck. The only idea I have is that you can try to push notifications that only set different badge number (without view and sound) and when you are inside you app download rest of the data. However, I'm not sure how good this idea is.